# Syntax error when running setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, gcc, pip

I am trying to run the installation of the `OBITools` package using the developers python script.

When running the installation as suggested `python get-obitools.py`, I receive the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip_build_tamara/OBITools/setup.py", line 39, in <module>
    from obidistutils.core import setup
  File "distutils.ext/obidistutils/core.py", line 27, in <module>
    from obidistutils.command.build_sphinx import build_sphinx
  File "distutils.ext/obidistutils/command/build_sphinx.py", line 15, in <module>
    from sphinx.setup_command import BuildDoc as ori_build_sphinx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/setup_command.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 22, in <module>
    from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive, directives, roles
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from docutils.parsers.rst import roles, states
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/roles.py", line 78, in <module>
    from docutils.utils.code_analyzer import Lexer, LexerError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/utils/code_analyzer.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pygments.formatters.html import _get_ttype_class
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygments/formatters/html.py", line 554
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using: 
Ubuntu 19.10
Python 2.7.17
Python 3.7.5

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: "I am using: Python 2.7.17 Python 3.7.5": which one (of the two versions)? You can't use both at the same time, and the SyntaxError is exactly the result of a Python 2/3 version mismatch.

Comment: In this case, you're attempting to install a Python 3 script or package with Python 2. That could be because `OBITools` doesn't support Python 2, or that it has its dependencies defined incorrectly (given that the error originates from the `pygments` package).

Comment: @00 according to the error trace, he/she is using python2.7

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am using Python 2.7 to execute the command. When using Python3 I get the error message: `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(install_zip)?`

Answer (score 0):

You'll be a bit stuck: OBITools requires Sphinx version < 2. Sphinx version requires Pygments version >= 2. The most recent Pygments verion(s) require Python 3, but OBITools requires Python 2.

So it appears the problem is in Sphinx's dependency settings.

One possibility is to install a Pygments version that is still Python 2 compatible (but still is version >= 2 for Sphinx). Then, Sphinx should pick that up automatically when it gets installed through OBITools dependencies.

[Pygments version 2.5 might just do the trick](https://pypi.org/project/Pygments/2.5.2/):

```
pip install pygments==2.5
```

---

Alternatively, you could try and push for a Python 3 version of OBITools, since Python 2 has been abandoned since 1-1-2020. However, since there has a been a ticket in its repository for a while without any response, this appears unlikely to happen (especially given that Python 3 has been out for years).

My preferred advice would be to abandon OBITools, given that it appears to live in the past.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to install the right versions of Sphinx and Pgyments manually. I've installed pygments 2.5.2. Error unfortunately still persisted. Now trying to install Sphinx 1.8.5, but get the error message `ERROR: Package 'sphinxcontrib-websupport' requires a different Python: 2.7.17 not in '>=3.5'`Is there any way around python 3.7?

Comment: @Tamara Use `python2` explicitly, instead of `python`. That should hopefully avoid the use of Python 3.

Comment: If that doesn't work, and Sphinx 1.8 has coded its dependency on sphinxcontrib-websupport coded badly (i.e., it allows a version that only supports Python 3), you can do the same trick, and install a recent version of sphinxcontrib-websupport before installing Sphinx. It's a rabbit hole, but that can happen with software from the past.

Comment: thanks, I've tried to use python2 explicitly, but it didn't work. I will switch to a new release of Obitools (still in beta, though), which is compatible with python2. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

The code causing an error uses `print` as a function, but in Python 2 it was a statement, therefore it throws a syntax error.

As discussed in the comments OBItool installs a package (Sphinx) which has a requirement (pygment) not supporting python2. You need to clone the OBItools from the repository https://git.metabarcoding.org/obitools/obitools/tree/master, change the Spinx package version in `requirements.txt`. The Sphinx 2.0 drops support for python 2 https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/CHANGES#L1013, so choose some older one like `1.8.0`

Then install the OBI tools using `python3 setup.py install` command.

Comment: According to the official documentation of [OBI tools](https://pythonhosted.org/OBITools/welcome.html), it works only on python2. Also, I think the error has nothing to do with `print`.

Comment: Then the requirements inside OBI tools are messed up, as they install pygments package in a version which does not support python 2. The error is caused by print statement used as a function here: https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/master/pygments/formatters/html.py#L552-L554

Comment: When running the command on Python3 I get the following error message: `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(install_zip)?`

Comment: It's not the requirements inside OBI tools, but those inside an older Sphinx version that cause this problem.

Comment: Unfortunatel,y the installation did still not work properly: I will switch to a new version of OBItools, which is still in beta but comparable with python3. Thank you for your help.